# Git plugin for Hudson checkout problem

Tags: git, hudson, github

When using the Git plugin for Hudson my job always fails when fetching the latest sources from my online git repository ( git://github.com/ithena/orm2dsl.git ) .

The git plugin first executes `git fetch` succesfully. Then it tries to execute `git checkout -f origin/` , which fails as shown below. Is this a problem with [my git repository](http://github.com/ithena/rose/tree/master) or is it the checkout command that makes no sense?

**Git command whithout a branch set in the job configuration:**

```
git checkout -f origin/
git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches/forcing
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

**Git command with branch set to master in the job configuration:**

```
git checkout -f origin/master
git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches/forcing
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/master' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

**Hudson console output:**

```
started
Checkout
[workspace] $ git fetch
Checking out origin/
[workspace] $ git checkout -f origin/
git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches/forcing
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/' which can not be resolved as commit?
FATAL: Error checking out origin/
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error checking out origin/
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launch(GitAPI.java:101)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.checkout(GitAPI.java:94)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:90)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:693)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:266)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:239)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:842)
    at hudson.model.Build.run(Build.java:88)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:70)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:90)
```

**Hudson Environment:** Debian Etch, Sun JSDK 6, git 1.4.4.4, hudson latest stable download

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your version of Git is pretty old. I suggest you update it before you do anything else.

Second, `git checkout -f origin/` is not a valid command. You either need to checkout a branch, or you can checkout a commit (by specifying the commit hash or a tag) and create a new branch of it at the same (using `git checkout -b new-branch commit-hash`). See the [git-checkout man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) for further details.

Comment: Updating git to v1.5.6 and explicitly specifying a branch did the trick.