# How do you set up Hudson to work with Git?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, hudson

I'm trying to set up Hudson as a CI Server and I'm having trouble getting everything to work.  I'm trying to use the 'official' git plugin.  I haven't done any testing with the alternate plugin developed by stephenh.

I'm wondering if anyone else has gotten Hudson to work with Git or any CI server to work with Git.  If so, how and with what configuration.

Pertinent information is that I'm on Hudson 1.277, I'm using Git 1.6.1.1.230.gdfb04, and the Git Plugin 0.5, all on the windows platform.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the upcoming 2.1. release Hudson will have the git plugin as part of the default install.  Even now the git plugin works like a charm.

In a nutshell you configure your git installation in the global configuration and then specify repo url and branch in the project config.

Check out the Hudson book for more information on how to configure things and such.

http://www.simpligility.com/2011/06/hudson-book-changes-and-community/

Update: The book is now available at http://wiki.eclipse.org/The_Hudson_Book

Comment: That release is now out! Go get it.

Answer (score 3):

[Git plugin for Hudson checkout problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499316/git-plugin-for-hudson-checkout-problem)

found that on my travels, thought it might help you out

Answer (score 3):

My experience with the Hudson git plugin 0.5 on Linux has been very positive.  It works great.

My experience with the Hudson git plugin 0.5 on Windows has been consistently negative.  I encountered Hudson [bug 2762](https://hudson.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2762), "/ is added to path of clone destination, Windows won't clone to that destination"

When I switched to the Hudson git plugin pre-release 0.6 from stephenh (on Windows), I was able to use git on Windows with Hudson.

Stephen Haberman's improvements are mentioned at [kernel trap](http://kerneltrap.org/index.php?q=mailarchive/git/2008/12/23/4478444/thread).  I confirmed that his target/git.hpi works in my Hudson version 1.290 installation.  I believe it is located at http://github.com/stephenh/hudson-git2/

There is a surprising message when Hudson 1.290 starts with Stephen's plugin.  Hudson reports:

```
Mar 10, 2009 7:57:36 AM hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter doUnmarshal
WARNING: Cannot convert type hudson.util.DescribableList to type hudson.model.Hudson$CloudList
Mar 10, 2009 7:57:36 AM hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter doUnmarshal
WARNING: Skipping a non-existent field repositories
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.NonExistentFieldException: No such field hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.repositories
```

However, even with those messages, I was still able to clone my repository.  I haven't done detailed testing yet, but preliminary results look promising.