# Hudson git commands are *incredibly* slow

Tags: windows, git, hudson

I have installed msysgit, and I am attempting to use it inside of Hudson. Whenever I run a command in an interactive shell, whether it be git-bash or a command prompt, the commands are instant. When I run them in Hudson, they lag for a *very* long time.

Running `/bin/git help` took 63 seconds when I just invoked it. I've never waited long enough to see a clone begin outputting (>10 minutes).

The Hudson mailing list is down, so I figured I would try here...

Comment: We see the same problem 4 years later.

Comment: And now that we finally did what ccutrer suggested it is fixed.

Answer (score 5):

I've run into this problem as well, and figured out a workaround.  When Hudson runs as a service, something is missing that your normal desktop environment has, which causes something to do with the network to have to re-load for each process.  msys-1.0.dll attempts to load something in netapi32.dll which causes it to take so long.  So I just downloaded plink.exe from PuTTY, and set my GIT_SSH env to use that instead.  Problem averted.

Comment: We have been struggling like forever on the problem and this seems to be the solution. +1M Kudos for this answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Git](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Git+Plugin) plugin for Hudson?

Comment: Yes, but I had several problems/concerns. Would it recognize my keys correctly from ~/.ssh/? Does it just do a clone and then execute any of your commands listed below? My main problem was that it tries to delete the 'workspace' directory and Windows won't let it. It says something is accessing it, although I don't have an `lsof` to see.

Comment: I've only used SVN with Hudson, but it wasn't very hard to configure. I let Hudson manage the workspaces for each job, which allowed it to delete them as necessary, and never had any issues with that.

Comment: Perhaps the answers here will be of assistance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534308/how-do-you-set-up-hudson-to-work-with-git

Comment: Using the plugin, I get:

GitAPI created
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository origin
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone git@platforms:foo.git
ERROR: Cause: Error performing  clone -o origin git@platforms:foo.git C:\hudson\jobs\Foo Periodic Build\workspace
null
Trying next repository
ERROR: Could not clone repository
FATAL: Could not clone
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone

Comment: Damn, that looks pretty bad. Could it possibly be a permissions issue?

Comment: This eventually started working, but I don't know how I fixed it. I'm currently using msysgit with the git plugin and a plink wrapper for my SSH.