# Jenkins (Windows) very slow Git fetch

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, git-fetch

We are experiencing slow git fetch commands on a Jenkins installation on Windows Server 2012. I have tried all the solutions mentioned in these threads:

- [Hudson git commands are *incredibly* slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891172/hudson-git-commands-are-incredibly-slow) (Using plink.exe from PuTTY and setting GIT_SSH to use that)
- [Jenkins hanging at "Fetching upstream changes from origin"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708490/jenkins-hanging-at-fetching-upstream-changes-from-origin) (Changed Jenkins to use cmd\git.exe instead of bin\git.exe)

Anyone been able to find a solution to this with a permanent fix?

Console output log from Jenkins:

> Started by remote host
>
> Building on master in workspace F:\Jenkins\jobs\xxx\workspace
>
> > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>
> Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>
> > git.exe config remote.origin.url xhttp://scm/git/xxx # timeout=10
>
> Fetching upstream changes from xhttp://scm/git/xxx
>
> > git.exe --version # timeout=10
>
> using .gitcredentials to set credentials
>
> > git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Users\APP_JE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\git7476037793811743133.credentials\" # timeout=10
>
> > git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress xhttp://scm/git/xxx +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

**PROBLEM HERE: The above command can take between 30 seconds to 120 seconds. On a local dev machine it takes a few seconds.**

> > git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10

Version info:

> Jenkins: 1.608 (latest)
>
> Windows: Server 2012
>
> Git: 1.9.5 (latest for Windows xhttp://git-scm.com/download/win)
>
> Git Client plugin for Jenkins : 1.16.1 (latest)
>
> Git plugin for Jenkins: 2.3.5 (latest)

Jenkins is running as a domain user which has administrator access on the server

Comment: Did you try to reinstall git as mentioned [here][1] ?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4506192/779338

Comment: Yes i have tried that. It doesn't help. I also applied these 3 config options without luck:

`$ git config --global core.preloadindex true`
`$ git config --global core.fscache true`
`$ git config --global gc.auto 256`

Comment: Is you server behind a different proxy than the local machines? We sometimes have issues with our proxy scanning all the files, which takes some time.

Comment: @michaelbahr no, it is not. Running the command manually from the server with git Bash is no problem. This is an issue with git & Jenkins combined.

Comment: Any update on this Thomas? We're seeing the same thing here.

Comment: Not yet @Webjedi. Will try DavidNeiss answer when i return from holidays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Version 2.6.1 of the Git client for Windows](https://git-scm.com/downloads)  fixes this problem. Now it's running blazingly fast!

I am using the git cmd in Jenkins from:

> C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

Comment: Finally! This has been messing with my mind for almost two years now!

Comment: Where is version 2.6.1?  As of today, Git appears to be at 2.26.0.  I am still experiencing slow fetches with this latest version.  Even after setting the --depth to 1 through 'Advanced Clone behaviors' and increasing the timeout.

Answer (score 2):

Use Advanced clone behaviors and enable the checkbox for "Do not fetch tags" if you don't need them. Git should still checkout the branch/tag you specify.

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable some of GIT's debug/performance flags to get more info on where things are taking time inside of its plumbing, see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables. For instance, `export GIT_TRACE=1` and also try GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE and GIT_TRACE_PACKET.

Comment: Any idea how i would enable these flags with the Jenkins Git plugin, and how to see the output of these flags afterwards?