# Integrating GIT into Hudson

Tags: .net, git, hudson, hudson-plugins

I have a Hudson project setup, basically "URL of repository" = D:/Development

Say I have a .NET solution under /SomeFolder/SomeProject/SomeProject.sln, how can I get Hudson to monitor the /SomeFolder/SomeProject folder in Git?  I am new to git, so should I have a new Git repository for each project?  I have used SVN with Hudson and was able to do the above easily, so any help would be greatly appreciated

Regards,

Andrew

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you set up Hudson to work with Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534308/how-do-you-set-up-hudson-to-work-with-git)

Comment: I did see that... my question is more like, in svn I can have sub folders with multiple solutions/projects and in Hudson I can monitor just 1 sub folder for changes, but I appear not to be able to do this with Git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see this kind of setting possible would be to use a parent repo, which would declare each of the repos you want to monitor as **[submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update)**.

Hudson might need to be tweaked in order to run a job before your current job, in order to make sure it does the `git submodule update` properly, before its '`git status`' (I haven(t tested this configuration, so maybe this step won't be necessary).

Comment: Are you able to tell me how you setup your git repo's for Hudson? I ended up setting up a repo for each solution, but would like to know if this is the right way of doing it... Like I said, I am new to git, so I'm just trying to work out best practice, etc

Comment: @andrewjboyd: intuitively, I would say that one repo per solution sounds right (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899373/transferring-legacy-code-base-from-cvs-to-distributed-repository-e-g-git-or-mer/899428#899428). If those repos aen't too closely related (i.e. if modifying one doesn't involve modifying *all* the others), then you can group them in a parent repo as submodules. What I don't know is how well Hudson will detect changes in said submodules when only the parent repo is set in the job configuration.

Comment: This is what I went with and it does handle it (after you check the "{something} submodule" check box)